# Reset jquery listview collapsible content after initiate filter

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a listview with collapsible content. The filter automatically expand the collapsible content. This is done through javascript.
After I reset the search filter, all items list remain expanded. How can I reset to initial state (collapsed)?

Here is the code:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tzontonel/8xjs9xxq/)

```
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function() {

        $("#iamalist").on('updatelayout', function() {

            if (($('#iamalist li').length - $('#iamalist .ui-screen-hidden').length) < $('#iamalist li').length) {
                $('#iamalist li').each(function() {
                    $(this).find('.ui-collapsible-content').removeClass('ui-collapsible-content-collapsed');
                    $(this).find('.ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');
                    $(this).find('.ui-icon-plus').removeClass('ui-icon-plus');
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div data-role="content" id="iama">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="iamalist" data-inset='true' data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search term is...">
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>eu</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>tu</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>voi</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Answer.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Answer.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one function. Instead of the updatelayout on the list, use the filterable **[widgit's Filter event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#event-filter)**. This event fires after every filter action. Within the handler check for the class `.ui-screen-hidden` within the list. If none exist, collapse all collapsibles otherwise expand them.

The collapsible widget has methods for **[collapse](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-collapse)** and **[expand](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-expand)** that you can use.

```
$("#iamalist").on("filterablefilter", function( event, ui ) {       
    if ($("#iamalist .ui-screen-hidden").length == 0){
       $('#iamalist [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible( "collapse" );
    } else {
        $('#iamalist [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible( "expand" );
    }    
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8xjs9xxq/51/)**